# Get date time in specific format in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the date time in moment js in this format :

```
2016-12-19T09:43:45.672Z
```

The problem is I am able to get the time format as

```
2016-12-19T15:04:09+05:30
```

using

```
moment().format();
```

but I need the format as the first one [like .672Z instead of +05:30]. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Probably you can simply use moment's [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation on the `format` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

Since "Z" is a format token for the timezone, you need to escape it. So the format string you are after is:

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]');
```

As @VincenzoC said in a comment, the [toISOString()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) method would also give you the format you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateTime = new Date("2015-06-17 14:24:36");
dateTime = moment(dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Try this. You should have the date in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Use moment.utc() to display time in UTC time instead of local time:

```
var dateValue = moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') + 'Z';
```

or moment().toISOString() to display a string in ISO format (format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, the timezone is always UTC):

```
var dateValue = moment().toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
    const start_date = '2018-09-30';
    const t = moment(start_date).utc().format();
    console.log(t);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```